# Alternativa ao $.html(''); para limpar uma div no Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou tendo problemas com cache em uma página pois são três chamadas no evento de `.change();` de 3 `input[type='select']` assíncronas com `jQuery`, porém quando faço uma nova selação no  primeiro `select`, por algum motivo fica *cache* do antigo valor enviado para a página por assíncrono.

Enfim, existe alguma outra alternativa ao `$("#minhaDiv").html('');` para limpar todo o conteúdo da `DIV` ?

Existem 3 selects com 3 divs:

```
<html>

<select id='select1' name='select1'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<select id='select2' name='select2'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<select id='select3' name='select3'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<div id='divSelect1'></div>
<div id='divSelect2'></div>
<div id='divSelect3'></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#divSelect1").on('change', function(){

$('#divSelect2').empty();
$('#divSelect3').empty();

var cat_four_value = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'push/' + cat_four_value + '/',
    data: { value: cat_four_value },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#divSelect1').load('select-details/1');
    }
});

}

$("#divSelect2").on('change', function(){

$('#divSelect3').empty();

var cat_four_value = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'push/' + cat_four_value + '/',
    data: { value: cat_four_value },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#divSelect2').load('select-details/1');
    }
});

}

$("#divSelect3").on('change', function(){

var cat_four_value = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'push/' + cat_four_value + '/',
    data: { value: cat_four_value },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#divSelect3').load('select-details/3');
    }
});

}

);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Não sei como está seu código, pois, não postou. Mas uma alternativa poderia ser utilizar o método **remove()** do jQuery.

Comment: @LeAndrade remove(); não apaga também a div ?

Comment: @sam não resolveu o problema, tá igual a html('').

Comment: @LeAndrade preciso remover apenas o conteúdo interno mesmo, não apagar a DIV, pois ela não é criada, ela é apenas alimentada com conteúdo no evento.

Comment: @AngeloJ a sua pergunta quer uma alternativa ao `.html('')`, no caso, é o `.empty()`. Agora, se resolveu ou não o seu problema é outra história. :D... mas vamos analisar melhor...

Comment: Incrementei a pergunta, talvez ajude a me ajudarem.

Comment: Pois é, como disse não tinha visto seu código, pois não havia postado!

Comment: O código tem vários erros. Faltam parênteses para fechar os eventos após os `}`.

Comment: É que digitei aqui, mas no console não dá erro não, mas vou fechar o tópico, vou refazer de outro modo,  pensei e pensei e decidi fazer de um modo mais simples. Obrigado por tudo e pela atenção prestada, sucesso fera!

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Você pode usar o método `.empty()`, que remove todos os elementos filhos da `div` selecionada:

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#minhaDiv").empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minhaDiv">
   <div>filho 1</div>
   <div>filho 2</div>
</div>
<button>Limpar div</button>
```

**[Documentação](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)**